# Django Class Based View Composite

Tags: django, view, composite, django-class-based-views

I'm using Django 1.3's Class-base generic views for a project. They're really nice but I would like to be DRYer. I have a page that displays a list of press coverage we've received and another which displays a list of articles we've published. On the overview page I need to display both lists. I would like to create a composite view which accepts both views and creates a context with both querysets attached.

Comment: Instead of updating your post, you should Answer your own question. That way the community can tell at a glance that there's a solution, and what it is.

Comment: When I started with Django I started found generic views to be the tool for almost everything. I modified, patched, and fixed that to do what I wanted. Problem was, that's not the thing they are solving. As soon as you step over the limit of what they are intended for, just use a normal view instead.

Comment: @Dave I moved Kenzic's solution into an answer and flagged the answer in hope that moderators will attribute it to Kenzic instead of me.

Answer (score 4):

[Kenzic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648439/kenzic) was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

**composite.py:**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateResponseMixin, View

class BaseCompositeView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):

    composite_views = []

    def get_composite_views(self):
        return self.composite_views

    def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        composite_views = self.get_composite_views()
        for composite_view in composite_views:
            cls = composite_view[0]
            try:
                clsview = cls.as_view(**composite_view[1])
            except IndexError:
                clsview = cls.as_view()

            view = clsview(request, *args, **kwargs)
            context_data = view.context_data
            context.update(context_data)

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from composite import BaseCompositeView
from .models import *


class MediaCoverageList(ListView):
    queryset = MediaCoverageItem.objects.order_by('-date')


class PressKitList(ListView):
    queryset = PressKit.objects.all()


class NewsroomLanding(BaseCompositeView):
    template_name = 'newsroom/landing.html'
    composite_views = [
        (MediaCoverageList,{
            'paginate_by': 10,
        },),
        (PressKitList,)

    ]
```

Comment: If you do not want to earn rep as the result of someone's answer, then you can switch it to CW.  Additionally, two months have gone by and Kenzic has not created an answer; it's reasonable for others to step in and provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can override the get_context_data method to add additional data to the context?

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(AuthorListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['press_list'] = Press.objects.all()
        context['articles_list] = Article.objects.all()
        return context
```

and in your template you can get the press list and the article list using `{{ press_list }}` and `{{ articles_list }}`.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, a view is simply one page. A view can have several forms, which I think is a better solution in your example.

Just split the template into several files, where each form have a small template, and use the template include directive to stitch it together. This also has the added advantage that the form can be reused in other views very simple.

Your solution is basically like frames but on the server instead of in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple way:**

Don't use a generic view and the [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/pagination/) object manually on both queryset.

It won't be that long, and it's not some lines that are going to kill your DRY IMO.

**The generic but long way:**

Create a view that wrap the `__init_`_ and `get_context` methods to pass argument to two ListView instances.

**init** should instanciate both `ListView`, pass the parameters and add the instances to attributes of the wrapper.

`get_context` should call the both get_context Listview instances method, and merge them into one context object.

Be sure to setup a different `template_object_name` for each `ListView` so they don't override each other in the context dict.

Do that in a generic way, and don't forget to pusblish you code on [djangosnippet](http://djangosnippets.org/) :-)